# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()' using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, guava

I am writing selenium code and have the below test method. I am not able to launch chrome browser due to this error. Please help me out.

```
@Test
public void test1()
{
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Automation", Keys.ENTER);
    driver.quit();
}
```

When I try to run Selenium with testng , I receive that error.
As a solution, I have added guava in pom.xml but the error still persists.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the error stack:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector 
com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilitiesUtils.makeW3CSafe(CapabilitiesUtils.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilitiesUtils.makeW3CSafe(CapabilitiesUtils.java:70)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4747)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4755)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION(DriverCommand.java:65)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:230)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:151)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:46)
at com.qa.tests.LoginPageTests.test1(LoginPageTests.java:20)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using ***Selenium v4.4.0*** through [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) dependency, you don't need to explicitly add the guava dependency. Simply adding the ***Selenium v4.4*** dependency should work out of the box:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Incase you are having transitive dependency in `pom.xml` which downgrades/updates *`guava`* version only in such cases you may have to explicitly add the required guava dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even if I remove the guava, it still has the same error.

Comment: Possibly `.m2` i.e _MAVEN_HOME_ got corupted. Delete `.m2` and then _mvn clean install test_

Comment: Actually I did that also, I deleted m2/repository, then did a maven purge local repository, after that I did mvn clean and mvn install.